# cms start: plone or modx

Tags: content-management-system, plone, modx, concrete5

I'm modelling a new project that will require a CMS solution. I'm a newb in this space ... I'm an old timer with typical enterprise skills of my era: scripting, java/j2ee, plsql. Working with jQuery and nodejs on other learning projects. For the CMS project, I've whittled down the many choices to Plone or Modx. Why? Both are good choices. Plone intrigues me because of the Python base - Python would be a nice add to my toolbox. Kinda wish Plone5 was a little closer. Modx strikes me as the best of my php based CMS solutions for a hands on developer type. I like they just made a big leap forward in their codebase. Concrete5 was a finalist here too. Drupal just sorta bugs me ... don't see me being a Drupal "guy". Joomla? Really ... not sure. Wordpress? Like going to a new restaurant and ordering a burger and fries. Would like to know opinions and reasons: Plone(python) or Modx(php)?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used Modx yet, but I can cast my vote for Plone. Especially if your project is not a simple website with one editor user.

Plone excels at powering complex sites with multiple users having different levels of access. Also, it's security track is the best in the area, ensuring you get a good night sleep, every night. On another note, in case your project is international: Plone is translated into more than 40 languages.

Interesting read:

- [Security Overview of Plone](http://plone.org/products/plone/security/overview)
- [Plone for Government sites](http://govfresh.com/2011/03/gov-2-0-guide-to-plone/)
- [List of sites running Plone](http://plone.org/support/sites)